# Comment traduire "wouldn't touch with a barge pole"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

En anglais il existe l'expression « wouldn't touch with a barge pole ». Elle veut dire que quelque chose est si mauvais ou indigne de confiance qu'on doit l'éviter à tout prix.  Existe-t-il une expression similaire en français ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pour quelque chose ou quelqu'un que l'on craint : *Je ne m'y frotterais pas*

Pour quelque chose de dégoûtant ou répugnant : *Je n'y toucherais pas, même avec des pincettes*.

NB: à ne pas condondre avec *prendre avec des pincettes*, prendre quelque chose ou une idée, avec réserve, modération

Comment: Attention, il faut bien noter que la traduction française ici est beaucoup moins péjorative et méchante que celle en anglais.

Answer (score 13):

Il existe plusieurs manières de parler d'une telle chose. Ça dépend en fait du contexte et de l'objet. Je pense par exemple à:

> Je n'en voudrais pas même si on me le donnait.

(pour un objet)

Ou encore

> Évite-le comme la peste.

(pour quelqu'un)

Cette liste n'est bien sûr pas exhaustive.

Comment: Je pensais aussi à « éviter comme la peste », mais je ne vois pas de raison de le limiter à des personnes.

Comment: Après réflexion, je pense que tu as raison, ça va aussi pour des animaux, des objets, des concepts, …

Comment: Ou des questions sur StackExchange :-/

Comment: +1 pour _fuir comme la peste_, qui a le défaut cependant d'avoir une traduction littérale _avoid like the plague_

Answer (score 4):

Je suis à peu près sûr que « je ne m'en approcherais pas à moins de cent mètres » est une traduction naturelle.

Answer (score 1):

C'est très informel, mais dans le dialecte québecois on peut utiliser : "J'y toucherais pas avec une pôle de cent pieds".

Qui pourrait être utilisé, dans un français syntaxiquement correct, comme suit : "Je n'y toucherais pas avec une pôle de cent pieds". À mon oreille, ça n'a toutefois pas le même impact ;)

C'est en fait la traduction la plus proche de l'expression anglaise que tu peux avoir.

Pour mes amis français, voilà la traduction littérale (évidemment, c'est une farce)

" Je n'y toucherais pas avec une perche de 30.48 mètres " ;)

Comment: « Une pôle de cent pieds » est (doublement) incompréhensible de ce côté-ci de l'Atlantique.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai ajouté une traduction pour toi :p

Comment: Le peu d'impact qui restait est définitivement éteint avec cette traduction ;-)